# How compare classes with generic types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

How can I write the below code with `is T`

```
public IList<IElement> OfClass(Type type)
{
    return list
        .Where(o => o.GetType() == type)
        .ToList();
}
```

Something like this:

```
public IList<IEtabsElement> OfClass(....)
{
    return list
        .Where(o => o is ...)
        .ToList();
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is my solution, so far. Is it okay?

```
public IList<IElement> OfClass<T>()
{
    return list
        .Where(o => o is T)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is 'list' in `return list`?  Is that supposed to be a parameter passed to your function?

Comment: Well you'd need it to be a generic method... but perhaps you're looking for the existing `OfType` method?

Comment: @JasonBoyd list is a field in the class defined like this: private IList<IElement> list;

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon, I still have problem understanding this. I want to be able to be able to pass a type of class that inherits IElement to this method and then return the list of IElement that are of this type. Maybe I'm not asking the question correctly.

Comment: @Vahid: Perhaps you just need `where T : IElement` to constrain `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic method instead:

```
public IList<T> OfClass<T>()
{
    return list
        .Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(T))
        .ToList();
}
```

This would work, but is the same as the existing method `OfType`, for example:

```
var myvehicles = new List<Vehicle> { new Car(), new Bike()};
var mycars = myvehicles.OfType<Car>();
```

Comment: `o.GetType() == typeof(T)` is not the same as `o is T`. Suppose for example that `T` is an interface or an abstract class. Then `GetType()` can never give `typeof(T)`; the actual (run-time) type will be something concrete. But it is still meaningful to ask if `o is T`. ___Edit:___ In your example, if there is a `RacingCar` (which "is" a `Car` but whose type is not exactly `Car`) in the list, what do you want?

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks Kenneth, your answer and Jeppe's comment pointed me  to the right direction.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I updated the original question with an answer. is this what you meant?

Comment: @Vahid Yes, but it depends on what you want. If you want to check if the type of `something` at run-time is ___exactly___ `T`, you would use `something?.GetType() == typeof(T)`. If you want to check if the type of `something` at run-time is "compatible" with `T`, i.e. equal to `T` or something deriving from `T` or implementing `T` (including value types boxable to `T`), or convertible to `T` because of co-/contravariance, etc., you would use `something is T`. When you use `is`, you get a warning if the result is known at compile-time.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks , although this answer given by Kenneth does not implement what I wanted, but your comments make it complete. I'm choosing this as the accepted answer.